# How can I change a file name that I uploads and don't change the extensions

Tags: php, laravel, file

So I'm uploading an image and I want to change the name of it to:

```
logo_{{Auth::user()->firstName}}_{{Auth::user()->lastName}}
```

and I want to keep the extension.
In my controller I have :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class UploadController extends Controller {

    public function upload(){

        if(Input::hasFile('file')){

            echo 'Uploaded';

            $file = Input::file('file');
            $file->move('uploads  ', $file->getClientOriginalName());
            $custom_name = 'logo_{{Auth::user()->firstName}}_{{Auth::user()->lastName}}'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            echo '<img src="uploads/' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '"/>';
        }

    }
}
```

So yes actually it's getClientOriginalName so ofc it will keep the same name, but how can I change it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have syntax issues, please follow below snippet

```
$custom_name = "logo_".Auth::user()->firstName."_".Auth::user()->lastName.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file->move(public_path('uploads'), $custom_name); // destination path, name of file
```

Comment: $custom_name is in unused state so it's not working :/

Comment: @Bastien I made changes in my answer now check.

Comment: I have this error when I upload the image : "The file "blablacar.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error."

Comment: Where is your uploads folder? means in which parent folder? public or storage?

Comment: So I have no error anymore (Stupid error from me) But, its does not change the name

Comment: And the uploads folder is in public